# Angular tree table tree structure representation

Tags: angular, treeline

this is stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3mtdxo?devtoolsheight=33&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

here need to put tree line to show tree-representation-structure

pls can anyone help?

Comment: there is indentation there... you need lines?

Comment: @AkberIqbal yes,, tree line to show tree-structure